LibreNMS only shows a few data points for one of my servers, how do I fix that?
I have a few PowerEdge servers that are very similar models, all from the same generation. I added them all to LibreNMS using the same SNMP protocol version, all connected to iDRAC on the server.
For two of the servers, LibreNMS shows 85 or 86 data elements collected but for one of them it only shows 3 data elements. For the other servers it shows CPU usage, CPU temperature, drive status, etc. but for this one it only shows Global System Status, Intrusion Reading and Intrusion status.
One might think that that one server has features turned off or something, however, I also added my servers to Zabbix while I've been figuring out which monitoring solution I want to use. Zabbix gets all the fields for all the servers.
Running the SNMP debug capture in LibreNMS for the troublesome server and an identical model of server shows very similar returned data lengths. Diff tools show that they are very similar, mostly differences in values.
I also tried removing it from LibreNMS and adding it again but that didn't fix the problem either.
